# Nested forms and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to understand how to make a nested form of my models but I am struggeling with understanding how and what I need to do it. I have been reading the Rails documentation and looked at the railscast but they just mention the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method etc without explaining. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Per API of Rails it's said:

**Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent...**

**Example:** it shows how we can manage posts through Member, **fields_for** is used to manage associated fields in a form, passing it the name of the associated model and then loop through all of the associated post records and create a form builder for each of them.

```
#controller
def new
  @member = Member.new
end

#model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end

#form
<%= form_for @member do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :posts do |builder| %>
  <p>
    <%= builder.label :account %><br />
    <%= builder.text_area :account %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Rails API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html